# Number formatting (Money) in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, currency

I'm trying to format numbers with not decimal points or commas, I've tried number_format() and money_format() and can't seem to get the result I need.

---

**number_format($item->amount,2)**

Result: 14,995.00

---

**money_format("%i", $item->amount)**

Result: 14,995.00

---

I'm want to get the following numbers formatted correct.

14995 needs to be £149.95

6795 needs to be £67.95

What is the best way to get the result above?

Comment: Can you give us some code, especially what you've tried for `number_format` and `money_format`?

Comment: @Jb31 updated the question with the results thanks

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php

Comment: Your way to represent numbers is strange: Why should 14995 be printed as 1,499.50 (so 14995 / 10) but 6795 as 67.95 (so 6795 / 100)?

Comment: @Jb31 The value is money that is a response from an API and i need to to read friendly as money so 6795 would be £67.95 to display on the website.

Comment: @Rickstar ok, but what about 14995? Shouldn't it be 149.95 instead of 1,499.50?

Comment: @Jb31 sorry that was an error i've updated it now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [brick/money](https://github.com/brick/money) (disclaimer: I'm the author):

```php
use Brick\Money\Money;

// Instantiating from a decimal amount

$money = Money::of('67.95', 'GBP');
echo $money->formatTo('en_GB'); // £67.95

// Instantiating from a minor amount (cents)

$money = Money::ofMinor(6795, 'GBP');
echo $money->formatTo('en_GB'); // £67.95
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_GB.UTF-8'); // change if needed
echo money_format('%n', 6795 / 100);
```

returns

£67.95

for me, so that should work. As i mentioned in my comment, you probably can't get the code to both display 14995 as 1,499.50 (divide by 10) and 6795 as 67.95 (divide by 100), so I'd recommend refactoring the code accordingly.